# Continental divide between rivers Danube and Rhine in Germany (watershed vector data) in Google Earth

Tags: coordinate-system, line, google-earth, mapping, watershed

Is there a line available for Google Earth that is showing the continental divide between the Rhine river and the Danube river? For me, it would be crucial to see where the rainwater is going to go.

Comment: If you want to include your contact data, you can do this on your profile page: https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/223747/menno not in the question. You question is about finding data for Rhine/Danube watershed. As a map, you can find it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_watershed but I guess you want it as vector data.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Major River Basins of the World dataset](https://datacatalog.worldbank.org/search/dataset/0041426) provided by the The World Bank Data Catalog. Donwload the zip file, unzip it and load it to Google Earth. Right click on the river catchment areas you're interested in (Dabube, Rhine), go to properties and change the style/color: e.g. only outline, no fill and select different colors for both river catchments.

Also enter a name for each catchment so you can easily recognize it: In the "Places" panel on the left, you can then uncheck the visibility box of the whole dataset and just check on the visibility of the two rivers you're interested in.

You could also right click the entries and export/save them separately as kmz file with `Save place as...` to keep just these two river catchment areas you're interested in.

*Red: Danube, blue: Rhine river catchment/watershed:*
[image]